# Problem with TikZ and vertical alignment of text inside nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, diagrams

I have a problem in TikZ with the vertical alignment of text inside nodes.

With a very minimal example like this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  ->,
  thick, shorten >=1pt,
  >=latex,
  node distance=7mm,
  noname/.style={%
    rectangle, rounded corners=9pt,
    text width=11em,
    text centered,
    minimum height=3em,
    draw=black!50,fill=black!20
  }
]

\node[noname] (configload) {Loads config};
\node[noname] (varsdec) [right=of configload] {New variables};

\path (configload) edge node {} (varsdec);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this diagram:

[image: simple diagram generated]

which has the text wrongly aligned because of the letter `g` in the first box. It can be seen better if we cut this diagram, showing only text:

[image: only text]

Which is the parameter I have to set in order to align the text correctly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This situation is described in Section 5.1 *Styling the Nodes* of the pgfmanual; one possible solution is to explicitly declare `height` and `depth` for the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  ->,
  thick, shorten >=1pt,
  >=latex,
  node distance=7mm,
  noname/.style={%
    rectangle, rounded corners=9pt,
    text height=1.5ex,
    text depth=.25ex,
    text width=11em,
    text centered,
    minimum height=3em,
    draw=black!50,fill=black!20
  }
]

\node[noname] (configload) {Loads config};
\node[noname] (varsdec) [right=of configload] {New variables};

\path (configload) edge node {} (varsdec);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here I add an image showing that now the baseline of the text is aligned:

[image]

The red line showing the alignment was obtained by adding

```
\draw[help lines,red,<->] let \p1 = (configload.base), \p2 = (varsdec.base) in (-1.5,\y1) -- (6.5,\y1)
(-1.5,\y2) -- (6.5,\y2);
```

to the example code above.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo! That solved perfectly the problem. And also thanks for pointing out the section in the pgfmanual where this issue is covered.

Answer (score 14):

You can solve this by adding `anchor=mid` to the node's definition.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  ->,
  thick, shorten >=1pt,
  >=latex,
  node distance=7mm,
  noname/.style={%
    rectangle, rounded corners=9pt,
    text width=11em,
    text centered,
    minimum height=3em,
    draw=black!50,fill=black!20
  }
]

\node[noname,anchor=mid] (configload) {Loads config};
\node[noname,anchor=mid] (varsdec) [right=of configload] {New variables};

\draw[help lines,red,<->] ($(configload.base)-(2,0)$)--($(varsdec.base)+(2,0)$);
\path (configload) edge node {} (varsdec);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what the anchors `base` and `mid` are meant for, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

add some phantom text with the same height as the other one. For example

```
\node[noname,anchor=mid] (configload) {Loads config};
\node[noname,anchor=mid] (varsdec) [right=of configload] {\vphantom{g} New variables};
```

Comment: thanks, this was the easiest one