# How to center one node exactly between two others with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How can I center a TikZ node exactly between two others?

Hypothetically,

```
\node (a) {a}
\node (c) [right of=c] {c}
\node (b) [between={a,c}] {b}
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the `calc` library (see the pgfmanual 13.5 Coordinate Calculations - version October 25, 2010).

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[text height=2ex]
\node (a) {a};
\node (c) [right of=a] {c};
\node (b) at ($(a)!0.5!(c)$) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Notice that the syntax you used is wrong: each node should end with `;` and the node `c` can not be positioned at its right.

Notice that without specifying the `text height`, the nodes are not vertically aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node (c) [right of=a] {c};
\node (b) at ($(a)!0.5!(c)$) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See as reference [Problem with TikZ and vertical alignment of text inside nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/problem-with-tikz-and-vertical-alignment-of-text-inside-nodes).

The `calc` library, however, is not the only way to proceed. In his comment percusse suggested another approach:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[text height=2ex]
\node (a) {a};
\node (c) [right of=a] {c};
\path (a) -- (c) node[midway] (b) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

and I see even one more (ok, is not so convenient, but I report it for the sake of completness). Suppose you are using the `positioning` library and nodes are placed `on grid`; then for sure the node distance is set in some way so one could go as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\distance{1}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[text height=2ex, on grid]
\node (a) {a};
\node (c) [right=\distance cm of a] {c};
\node (b) [right=0.5\distance cm of a]{b};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Both approaches lead to the result shown in the first example picture.

Comment: The code was only hypothetical. Not meant to be working code(just enough to get the point across). Anyways, your method works. Thanks.

Comment: You can also add `\path (a) -- (c) node[midway] (b) {b};` to the list.

Comment: @percusse: absolutly right! Actually I see also another way besides your: I'll edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: Also, you can align the nodes with respect to their baseline to align them vertically, with `anchor=base`.

Comment: @Bordaigorl: are you sure? I suspect `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=base] (a) {a};
\node[anchor=base] (c) [right of=a] {c};
\node[anchor=base] (b) at ($(a)!0.5!(c)$) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}` won't vertically align a, b and c. Anyway, feel free to edit the answer with your example. :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: yes what you need is more than just setting the anchor, you also need to use it =)
`\node[anchor=base] (a) {at};
\node[anchor=base] (c) [base right=of a] {cg};
\node[anchor=base] (b) at ($(a.base)!0.5!(c.base)$) {b};
\draw (a.base) -- (c.base);` would do. Similarly you can use a `\path (a.base) -- (c.base) node[midway] (b) {b}`. Shall I edit the answer? Post another?

Comment: @Bordaigorl: as you like more. No problems from my side, and if you want to post a new answer, you have already got a +1 :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I added an answer because I also attempted at the definition of the `between` key. If you know better solutions, comments are welcome!

Comment: @Bordaigorl: excellent! Good idea the `between` key :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino You need to use `.5*\distance` in the last example. Otherwise you produce `.51cm` instead of `.5*1cm`. (Just use `2` as distance.) Instead of having three examples each with one solution, why don’t you add one example with all solutions, also showing the difference between them. (The one at the path places the new nodes between the *borders* of the other nodes (as long as you don’t specify an anchor or use a coordinate anyway), here between `a.east` and `c.west`, while `calc`’s syntax (again without anchors) places the new node between the centers.)

Comment: There is also the `barycentric cs` which you can use to place a node “between” more than two nodes (it works for two, too). `calc`’s not even needed. `:)`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: good point! As soon as possible I revise the answer :)

Comment: You might want to add that for centering text in node `b` between text in nodes `a` and `c`, the anchors `east` and `west` are very helpful.

Comment: @mrc: Unfortunately that's not always true. Try adding `draw` option to the nodes in the example where they're not aligned. You will discover that they have different heights. Hence, under such an hypothesis, it is not guarantee that the positioning via `.east` and `.west` anchors really achieves vertical alignment.

Comment: What I meant was in a case where node `(a)` has text {A} and node `(c)` has much wider text, e.g., `{cccc}`. In such a case you probably don't want the horizontal centering to be with respect to the center of `A` and the center of `cccc`, but rather with the right edge and left edge, respectively. I used this method yesterday and it worked very well (and I did vertical centering with `\strut`).

Answer (score 32):

In addition to @Claudio's detailed answer here's a more concise solution which also aligns the nodes with respect to the text's baseline without requiring an explicit specification of the text height.

The following does not require `calc` and only requires `positioning` because of the use of `base right` which is included to be faithful to the example in the question. Otherwise, absolute positioning (i.e. with `at`) would work as expected.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base]
    \node (a) {a};
    \node (c) [base right=of a] {c};
    \path (a.base) -- node (b) {b} (c.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Setting the `anchor` to `base` globally makes the code more concise but you can apply it to each node individually.

The third line creates the node `(b)` midway the line connecting the baselines of the other two nodes.

Also note that the key `right of` is deprecated in favour of `right=of ...` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9391/36686)).

---

## Addendum: how to create a `between` key

Here's a way to actually provide the syntax proposed in the question.

```
\tikzset{
    between/.style args={#1 and #2}{
         at = ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$)
    }
}
```

Then you can write something like `\node[between=a and c] (b) {b};`.
Again, if you want the baseline alignment you have to write `between=a.base and c.base` or write an abbreviation as

```
\tikzset{
    between base/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        between=#1.base and #2.base
    }
}
```

so you can just write `between base=a and c`.

This however requires the `calc` library.