# How to vertically align nodes of different sizes using relative positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I am trying to draw a timeline and I want to label an interval of time
using a horizontal double arrow such as `<--->`.
Unfortunately, because the nodes `$t$` and `$t + \ell_t$` have different heights,
the interval "Shipment lead time" is not exactly a horizontal line.
How do I fix the nodes so that they have the same height?

[image]

Comment: I think you can find some insights in [How to center one node exactly between two others with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71478/13304)

Comment: Use the perpendicular coordinate system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of changing the nodes, you can use the perpendicular coordinate system (compare the red inclined rule with the two horizontal black rules):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south] (A) {\Huge A};
\node[anchor=south] at (2,0) (B) {B};
\draw[red] (A) -- (B);
\draw (A) -- (B.west|-A);
\draw (A.east|-B.west) -- (B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`(<name1>|-<name2>)` has the `x`-coordinate of `<name1>` and the `y`-coordinate of `<name2>`; `(<name1>-|<name2>)` has the `y`-coordinate of `<name1>` and the `x`-coordinate of `<name2>`.

If, however, you want the nodes to have the same total height, assign equal values to the keys `text height` and/or `text depth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) {$t$};
\node[draw] at (2,0) (B) {$t_{l_{m}}$};
\draw[red] (A.south east) -- (B.south west);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\node[draw,text depth=0.35ex] (A) {$t$};
\node[draw,text depth=0.35ex] at (2,0) (B) {$t_{l_{m}}$};
\draw (A.south east) -- (B.south west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, the second approach is both intuitive and straightforward. Thanks!