# How to add an equal sign between two nodes in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I add an equals sign between the leftmost "A" and the next "A" to the right?

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,decorations,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{node} = [rectangle, draw, text centered]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.4cm]
        \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=gray!75,fill=gray!20,minimum size=6mm] 
        \node (ae) [node] {A};
        \node (a0) [node, right=1.5cm of ae] {A};
        \node (a1) [node, right of=a0] {A};
        \node (a2) [node, right of=a1] {A};
        \node (a3) [node, right of=a2] {A};
        \node (x0) [node, below of=ae] {$X_t$};
        \node (x1) [node, below of=a0] {$X_0$};
        \node (x2) [node, below of=a1] {$X_1$};
        \node (x3) [node, below of=a2] {$X_2$};
        \node (x4) [node, below of=a3] {$X_t$};
        \node (h0) [node, above of=ae] {$h_t$};
        \node (h1) [node, above of=a0] {$h_0$};
        \node (h2) [node, above of=a1] {$h_1$};
        \node (h3) [node, above of=a2] {$h_2$};
        \node (h4) [node, above of=a3] {$h_t$};
        
        
        \draw [red,->] (ae.45) arc (0:240:4mm) node[pos=0.5,above left]{}(ae);
        %\draw [=] (ae) -- (a0)
        \draw [arrow] (a0) -- (a1);
        \draw [arrow] (a1) -- (a2);
        \draw [arrow] (a2) -- (a3);
        \draw [arrow] (x0) -- (ae);
        \draw [arrow] (x1) -- (a0);
        \draw [arrow] (x2) -- (a1);
        \draw [arrow] (x3) -- (a2);
        \draw [arrow] (x4) -- (a3);
        \draw [arrow] (ae) -- (h0);
        \draw [arrow] (a0) -- (h1);
        \draw [arrow] (a1) -- (h2);
        \draw [arrow] (a2) -- (h3);
        \draw [arrow] (a3) -- (h4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just make a node there?

Comment: Alternatively use [How to center one node exactly between two others with TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71478/how-to-center-one-node-exactly-between-two-others-with-tikz) for accuracy

Comment: Note: You need to load `tikz` before any of the libraries. You have it reversed in your code. Also, the `\documentclass` is missing.

Answer (score 7):

The following gives a simpler code. No more library is needed; handy `\foreach` with 2 variables; `\a` and `\b` for controlling the vertical and horizontal distances.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\def\a{2} \def\b{2.2}
\foreach \i/\j in {-1/t,0/0,1/1,2/2,3/t}{
\path[nodes={draw}]
(\i*\b,0) node (a\i) {$A$}
+(0,\a)   node (h\i) {$h_{\j}$}
+(0,-\a)  node (x\i) {$X_{\j}$}
;
\draw[->] (a\i)--(h\i);
\draw[->] (x\i)--(a\i);
}

\draw[->] (a0)--(a1);
\draw[->] (a1)--(a2);
\draw[->] (a2)--(a3);
\draw[->,magenta] (a-1.north east) arc (0:240:.4); 
\path (a-1)--(a0) node[midway,blue]{=};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution!+1

Comment: Thanks! most people does not pay attention to the simplicity of code, and figures itself

Comment: Try `\newcommand\a{2}` :) An alternative is `declare function={a=2;b=2.2;}` in the options to the `tikzpicture`, and use `a`/`b` instead of `\a`/`\b` in the coordinates in the loop.

Answer (score 6):

The usage of the positioning library is `right=of ae` not `right of=ae`. So you should change all your nodes. Then you can add `\node [right=.7cm of ae.center]{=};` for your `=` sign, since your `node distance` is set to `1.4cm`.

[image]

```
    \node (ae) [node] {A};
    \node (a0) [node, right=of ae] {A};
    \node (a1) [node, right=of a0] {A};
    \node (a2) [node, right=of a1] {A};
    \node (a3) [node, right=of a2] {A};
    \node (x0) [node, below=of ae] {$X_t$};
    \node (x1) [node, below=of a0] {$X_0$};
    \node (x2) [node, below=of a1] {$X_1$};
    \node (x3) [node, below=of a2] {$X_2$};
    \node (x4) [node, below=of a3] {$X_t$};
    \node (h0) [node, above=of ae] {$h_t$};
    \node (h1) [node, above=of a0] {$h_0$};
    \node (h2) [node, above=of a1] {$h_1$};
    \node (h3) [node, above=of a2] {$h_2$};
    \node (h4) [node, above=of a3] {$h_t$};
    \node [right=.7cm of ae.center]{=};
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,
             width=7cm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                decorations,
                petri, positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=2em}
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\x]  in {t,0,1,2,t,5}
{
\ifnum\x=2
    \node (a\x) [N,on chain] {$A$};
\else
    \node (a\x) [N,on chain, join=by ->] {$A$};
\fi
\node (x\x) [N, below =of a\x] {$X_{\i}$};
\node (h\x) [N, above =of a\x] {$h_{\i}$};
\draw[->]   (x\x) -- (a\x);
\draw[->]   (a\x) -- (h\x);
}
\path(a1) -- node {$=$} (a2);  %  <---
\draw[red,->] (a1.45) arc (0:240:1.414em);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In it is used

- for `pgfplots`, which also load `tikz` package I suggest to use recent version `1.18` which introduce many new functionalities and fix may bugs from the "ancient" version onwards (it is time to upgrade your LaTeX installation).
- recent `tikz` syntax for defining styles of image elements (`\tikzstyle` is deprecated for long time ago)
- rows with nodes `A` are positioned by use of `chains` library and connected with exception the first two by macro `join = by ->`
- first two, what was your problem, are connected by `path` with node with `=` in the middle.

Result of MWE compilations is:

[image]