# tikz - placing two nodes side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf

*my preamble:*

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

---

Using tikz, I would like to write the word "event" and the word "cumulative" side by side. My problem is that the word "event" appears to be slightly above "cumulative"... Can you help me?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1st) {event};
\node[right=of 1st] (2nd) {cumulative};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason for this is that `l` and `i`is higher than `t`, thus the right node is bigger and its center lies higher than the center of the left node. You should be using `base right` or `mid right` instead. (You can also manipulate the nodes’ heights with `text height`.)

Comment: Have a look to [Problem with TikZ and vertical alignment of text inside nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/problem-with-tikz-and-vertical-alignment-of-text-inside-nodes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `right=of` TikZ actually places the `.west` anchor of the second node a specific distance *right* of the first node’s `.east` anchor. For nodes with different heights and depths those anchors (along with the `.center` anchor) do not lie the same distance from the baseline (anchors `.text`, `.base`, `.base west`, `.base east`).

When you use `base right=of` the anchors `.base west` (new node) and `.base east` (referenced node) are used. The same applies for the `mid` anchors and `mid right` as the `mid` anchors simply lie `.5ex` above the baseline.

You can also alter the height and depth of the nodes’ text boxes with the keys `text height` and `text depth` which has a different effect but may be more appropriate if you want to draw the nodes or use them for a vertical reference. You can still use `base right=of` here, of course. Instead of guessing or setting a specific text height/depth you can also use `\vphantom{<heighest and deepest characters>}` (for the `font` key) or `text height=\heightof{<heighest character>}` and so on.

In the example below I have used an exaggerated example.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{nodes={draw=gray, text=gray}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node               (1st) {evena};
\node[right=of 1st] (2nd) {cumulative\rule{.4pt}{2em}};

\draw (2nd.base) -- ++ (left:3);
\draw (2nd.center) -- (1st.center);
\draw[thick] (2nd.west) -- (1st.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node                    (1st) {evena};
\node[base right=of 1st] (2nd) {cumulative\rule{.4pt}{2em}};

\draw (2nd.base) -- ++ (left:3);
\draw (2nd.center) -- (1st.center);
\draw[thick] (2nd.west) -- (1st.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text height=2em]  (1st) {evena};
\node[right=of 1st]     (2nd) {cumulative\rule{.4pt}{2em}};

\draw (2nd.base) -- ++ (left:3);
\draw (2nd.center) -- (1st.center);
\draw[thick] (2nd.west) -- (1st.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image] [image] [image]