# Tikz: Alignment of labels relative to a split rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

Is there a way for accurate placement of labels relative to the center of each of the parts of a split rectangle? The following example shows two errors:

- Alignment is with the left side of the sub-part
- The vertical alignment seems to be wrong.

The following is a a minimal working example:

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
     date/.style= {
       rectangle split,
       rectangle split horizontal, 
       rectangle split parts=3,
       draw
   }]
   \node[date] (today) {
     \nodepart{one}   {\texttt{2014}}
     \nodepart{two}   {\texttt{01}}
     \nodepart{three} {\texttt{01}}
   };
   \node[below=2mm of today.one] {\texttt{y}};
   \node[below=2mm of today.two] {\texttt{m}};
   \node[below=2mm of today.three] {\texttt{d}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image: the above document when rendered]

Comment: The problem is caused by the different height of the text in the three nodes, an issue which has been discussed in many other questions (see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19751/36686) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133237/36686)). A quick fix: add `\strut` to the contents of the nodes i.e. `\node[...]{\texttt{\strut d\strut}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the horizontal alignment, place them relative to `today.one south` etc. To fix the vertical alignment set the anchor of the nodes to `base`, which is the baseline of the text.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
     date/.style= {
       rectangle split,
       rectangle split horizontal, 
       rectangle split parts=3,
       draw
   }]
   \node[date] (today) {
     \nodepart{one}   {\texttt{2014}}
     \nodepart{two}   {\texttt{01}}
     \nodepart{three} {\texttt{01}}
   };
   \node[below=3mm of today.one south,anchor=base] {\texttt{y}};
   \node[below=3mm of today.two south,anchor=base] {\texttt{m}};
   \node[below=3mm of today.three south,anchor=base] {\texttt{d}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a quick and accurate answer!